# Can I override built in wordpress elements in the block theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-block-theme

I am new to Wordpress, and I have started creating a custom theme to use with my site. I am using block themes as the wordpress documentation seems to imply that they are the most up-to-date way to work with wordpress themes, however I have reached a point where the standard blocks don't quite do what I want them to.

The situation is this: I have a `wp:query` block that I am using to display posts. Within that I have a `wp:post-template` element, and inside that there is a `wp:post-date` element. I want to reformat the `wp:post-date` so that is will display a tag icon before the post date.

I have tried doing this:
`<i class="fa-regular fa-calendar"></i><!-- wp:post-date /-->`,
however the post date tag renders a div with display block, causing the date to display on the line after the icon.

[image]

I have tried adjusting the layout so display is inline, but that doesn't work. I have also tried creating a pattern in php and using the `get_the_date()` function, but it seems this can only be used with classic themes relying on php for the template files.

Is there a way to make this work nicely in a block theme?

Thanks.